# Conditions on $\alpha$ such that the function is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ be a polynomial. For wich values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is the function
$$ f: (0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(x) = \frac{P(\sin x)}{x^\alpha} $$ integrable?

So we have to look into the behavior of this function for $x \rightarrow 0$ and $x \rightarrow + \infty$.

I find for $x \rightarrow 0$ that $\sin x = \Theta(x)$ so $P(\sin x) = \Theta(x^t)$, where $t$ is the lowest degree of $f$. It is evident that $x^\alpha = \Theta(x^\alpha)$. Therefore I find that $f(x) = \Theta(x^{t-\alpha})$ for $x \rightarrow 0$.

Hence $f$ is integrable in the neighborhood of $0$ when $\alpha - t < 1 \iff \alpha < t+1$.

Let us now look for $x \rightarrow \infty$. I think that $P(\sin x )= O(1)$ because $\sin x = O(1)$. Again, it is evident that $x^\alpha = \Theta(x^\alpha)$. Therefore I find that for $x \rightarrow +\infty$: $f(x) = O(x^{-\alpha}) $. So, if $\alpha >1$, we find that $f$ is integrable for $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

My question: am I correct until this point because I find it weird that I had to work with the lowest degree of $f$. Now because our last expression was only an $O$-expression, I have to check if $f$ is integrable if $\alpha \leq 1$. My intuition says that $f$ won't be integrable but I am not able to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For $x\rightarrow 0$, your proof is perfectly right. There is nothing strange about looking at the valuation (= the lowest degree with a non-zero coefficient). In fact as $|\sin|<1$, the $\sin^k$ that weighs the most is the one with the lowest $k$.

However I think you should work with equivalents : it avoids verification. You can say $P(\sin x) \sim a_k (\sin x)^k$ where $k$ is the valuation of $P$. So $\frac{P(\sin x)}{x^\alpha} \sim \frac{a_k}{x^{\alpha-k}}$. We recognize a classic Riemann integral, so we directly get that the function is integrable around $0$ **if and only if** $\alpha -k < 1$ (pay attention to the fact that I can say that because we work with positive functions : $|\sin x|$,...).

As for $x\rightarrow +\infty$, I think the function is not integrable when $\alpha \leqslant 1$ (I think you wrote $\alpha > 1$ instead).
Proof : I make the proof for $\alpha = 1$, the case $\alpha > 1$ is then immediate.

- I start with an instructive example : P = X.

Let's prove that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not integrable.
There are different ways to do it.
For example we can remark that for $k\in \mathbb{N}$:

$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{|\sin x|}{x} \geqslant \frac{\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} |sin|}{(k+1)\pi} = \frac{\int_{0}^{\pi} |sin|}{(k+1)\pi} = \frac{2}{(k+1)\pi}$.

As $\sum \frac{1}{k}$ diverges, we get that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not integrable

This example shows how to procede for the general case.

- For $P$ a polynome, we just need to show that $\int_{0}^{\pi} |P(\sin)|$ is not zero or negative, and it can be done easily either by calculating the integral, or by induction on the degree of $P$.
  Then we get that the function is not integrable.

Hope it helped.